# Keyboard Shortcut in Javascript to run a function

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a HTML page. I would like to call a function when <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> are pressed, e.g.:

```
var default = function(){
    alert("Called");
}
```

I have searched on Google but I am not sure it can run on IE8, IE9, IE10. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In my project I use https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster for that.

Comment: Can do it without any Javascript library?

Comment: You can you this as a reference: https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster/blob/master/keymaster.js#L267